# What ffmpeg codec should be used when mp3 file is encoded as 128kbs/44100kHz?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, gstreamer, encode

I was encoding mp3 files with `ffmpeg -i #{url}  -b:a 128k -vn -acodec copy -y output.file` and sending them to a gstreamer, and this was working perfectly. (Prior to this encoding, the gstreamer was throwing a variety of errors).

For unrelated reasons, I had to convert all files to a constant bit rate, so changed the encoding to:
`ffmpeg -i #{url}  -preset veryfast -ab 128k -ar 44100 -y output.file`

Now all of my errors are back. Is there a codec I should be using with the new encoding?

Comment: What's the format of `output.file`?

Comment: input and output are both mp3

Comment: If the output extension is mp3, then only mp3 or mp2 codec are supported. What errors do you get?  (Don't skip the `-vn`)

Comment: There is no encoding going on in the first invocation; -acodec copy means "copy the compressed audio data from the input without modifications", so -b:a 128k is ignored. All you're doing is changing the container format (like wav, mp4, etc.) or tags (like id3). The second invocation actually re-compresses, but without ffmpeg stdout/stderr it's impossible to say what happens exactly...

Comment: Thanks for your comments; they really helped me wrap my head around this more. It turned out that the files had embedded images in them. I didn't realize that `-vn` removed not just video but embedded and cover images as well. Thanks!